# Какой частью речи является слово "пока"?

Tags: части-речи

Какая часть речи — "пока"?

Ветки кустарника цеплялись за маскхалат, срывали с головы капюшон. Наверное, четверть часа лейтенант продирался через кустарник, *пока* наконец не вырвался в поле.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В вашей фразе "пока" - очевидный союз. Он присоединяет условие (время) действия второго сказуемого.

Вообще "пока" может быть наречием, союзом или частицей (близкой к междометию).

Всё это есть даже в словарях. Вот у Кузнецова.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x